# How to prevent all audio being played on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I need to find a way to have a mute button for my website. I have an onclick sound for my menu options but I would like to have a mute button to prevent all audio being played after mute is pressed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript for mute audio from  website

```
<button onclick="muteAudio()">Mute audio</button>    

    function muteAudio(){
        els=document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
        for (var j = 0; j < els.length; j++) {
        els[j].muted = true;
        }
        }
```